# Dynamic array inside a for statement

Tags: python, c++, django, algorithm, data-structures

I have a database with a lot of records and a code with *Django* framework. right now I run a query on that database and collect the results in a list. each record has a field called **priority**, then with a for statement process them one by one according that priority. But I have a problem.

My database is very dynamic and while I'm processing current list may I have a new record in database with a higher priority! I have to process it first but it current architecture, I can't, I have to wait to terminate current list processes. how i can achieve my goal?

I have an alternative way but i'm not sure that it is the best way. Inside a while statement, I can run a query to database and fetch only one record that has higher priority.

What's your opinion to my alternative solution? Is there a better way?

Comment: Not entirely sure how you're planning on detecting a DB update on a live row set from a prior query, but that may just be a django thing that is out of my wheelhouse. What is in my wheelhouse is this: [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) and an ordered query used in combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use treading to get threads that process or sub-process your high priority data with Queue, as said by WhozCraig.
Here's an example of how it could look like. If you want to use multiple threads and more functions than only run() you will have to redefine the thread object calling from  thread1_high_priority = High_priority_Thread(1, 10, queue)# where the parameters are defined in run() to 
 thread1_high_priority = High_priority_Thread(target= functionname, name = name)# and the same in **init**,  def **init** (self, target, name):.

```
import Queue
import threading
import time


queue = Queue.Queue()

class High_priority_first(threading.Thread):
    """ a threading class"""

    def __init__ (self, start, stop, queue):


        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.queue = queue
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

# Write a function, run(), that counts the higher priority data and extend it to
# also count lower priority, or create another function for low priority data and
# run them with a separate thread than thread 1.

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.start != stop:
                self.start += 1
                self.queue.put(self.start)

            else:
                break


thread1_high_priority = High_priority_Thread(1, 10, queue)# start at 1 and stop at 10
thread1_high_priority.start() #start thread1

thread2_lower_priority = High_priority_Thread(1, 3, queue)# start at 1 and stop at 3
thread2_lower_priority.start() #start thread2

while True:
    if queue != None: # check that queue isn't empty
        out =  queue.get()
        print out

    else:
        break
```